# Microchip documentation does not label CAN buss pins on micro controller pinout diagram

Tags: datasheet, microchip, can, pinout

**[Link to the data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70292G.pdf)**

I want to use Microchips `DSPIC33FJ128GP802` in a new project and want to use the `ECAN buss`.

The problem I'm facing is that in the `Controller families` list at the top of the data sheet it says that device `DSPIC33FJ128GP802` has one `ECAN port` as Remappable Peripheral:

[image: Controller families]

When I go down to the `Pinout descriptions` table and look for the `ECAN` pin labels it says that they are `C1RX` and `C1TX`:

[image: Pinout descriptions]

Until this point everything is perfect, I now know that this chip has a `CAN buss` somewhere and I know what the pins are called but now when I go to the pinout diagram for the chip:

[image: pinout diagram]

There are no pins that have the label `C1RX` or `C1TX`. So what am I supposed to to? should I guess where the `CAN` pins are or am I missing something here?

All help is appreciated XD

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The CAN pins do not have fixed pin assignments. Instead you are able to select which of the "Remappable Pins" you wish to use (RP0 through RP15).

If you refer to page 180 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70292G.pdf), specifically the table titled "REGISTER 11-16" (RPINR26: Peripheral Pin Select Input Register 26), it details the register used to select the CAN RX pin location (C1RXR).

For the CAN TX pin location, this is set by the RPnR register of the pin that you want to use as detailed in section 11.6 (Peripheral Pin Select) starting page 161.

Comment: Additionally, if you are making a PCB, load up MPLAB and make sure you can actually map to your desired pins. I've been bitten by wrong documentation in regards to remappable pins and ended up sans an SPI port! The same goes for any device (FPGA/MCU/whatever) with remappable ports.

Answer (score 4):

It is considered a 'remappable peripheral'.  You will need to map those to pins labelled RPX (where X is some number).

See section 4.8 of your datasheet.